# flex Text Layout Framework multilingual support

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, air, multilingual

I am using text layout framework in my application. I am using textflow as editor to my application. As text layout framework supports multiple languages. I a m able to see the text in multiple languages.

Now my doubt is, can I type in different languages? 
For example: As in word if we choose the font as Hindi then whatever we type it comes in Hindi.

I need just like that.

Is it possible with text layout framework?
If yes then how?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

(Duplicating my answer from the Text Layout Format forums http://forums.adobe.com/community/opensource/tlf)

It is possible. It works better in Flash Player 10.1 and AIR 2.0 than previous versions. If you've tried it out and it has not worked, please try upgrading your Player to a 10.1 beta and see if it works there.

Your operating system will have different input methods for each language. When (for instance) you turn on one of the Devanagari input methods on OSX, and you have a font with Hindi glyphs, when you type you will get Hindi.

Comment: Thanks Alan,
I tried with Flash Player 10.1 and AIR 2.0 but then also I was not able to type in Hindi. I have Hindi fonts installed on my system. 
Have one more doubt: Do I need to any setting with textflow control? 
Can you suggest any way out?